# Proportional segments between parallelogram and triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

In the figure, ABCD is a parallelogram, $F$ is in the prolongation of $AD$. If $EF=32$, $GF=24$ and $AD=DF$, $BE=?$

I made the drawing[image]

*My try:* I tried to do some proportions between the triangles $FDG$ and $BCG$ but got nothing. I'm 100% sure that this problem is about propotionality. Any hints?

Comment: What Kind of triangle is $$\Delta ABC$$?

Comment: the problem doesn't say anything about that triangle. We don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By intercept theorem, $BG=GF=24$

$BE=BG+GF-EF=24+24-32=16$

Comment: wouldn't be $BE=16$?

Comment: @RodrigoPizarro The two numbers reversed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Triangles DGF and ABF are similar.